# Why Windows is not giving me a window the size I asked?

Tags: windows, winapi

[image]
I'm trying to create a window with the client size the same as the display resolution (1366 x 768).

For this, I'm using AdjustWindowRectEx to get the calculated width and height of the window to be created.

The first red circle in the top right is the actual display resolution that I want the client size of the window to have.

The second red circle is the width and height that AdjustWindowRectEx calculated the window to be created with (client size + borders and title bar).

The last red circle in the bottom is the actual client size that I got after the window has been created.

The height is not what I ask Windows to give me. I asked 768 and I got 749.

Is there some limit height the window can be created with? No matter how much I ask the height to be, it never give me more than 749.

Thanks!

Comment: Depending on your version of Windows and configuration, have you tried AdjustWindowRectExForDpi

Comment: @SimonMourier AdjustWindowRectEx is not the problem, it calculates correctly. 807 - 768 = 39, which maybe is the borders and title bar sizes. But, 749 + 39 = 788, which is not what AdjustWindowRectEx calculated to be.

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Code is text, and can be copied and pasted directly into your question and formatted for readability. See [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the many reasons that images should be avoided unless the problem cannot be demonstrated in any other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CreateWindow(), [`WM_GETMINMAXINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-getminmaxinfo) information will be sent to confirm the size of the current form can be generated, you can refer to [`MINMAXINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-minmaxinfo?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to view its specific structure. If the size of the created form is larger than its default setting, it will be overwritten by the default size. So it will be smaller than the size you set when it is created.

According to the [`WM_GETMINMAXINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-getminmaxinfo):
An application can override the defaults by setting the members of [`MINMAXINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-minmaxinfo?redirectedfrom=MSDN), and return zero if an application processes this message.

Here is the sample:

```
 #include <Windows.h>
    LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM);
    
    static int max_right, max_bottom;
    int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
    {
        static TCHAR szAppName[] = TEXT("hello windows");
        HWND hwnd = 0;
        MSG msg;
        WNDCLASS wndclass;
        wndclass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
        wndclass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc; 
        wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
        wndclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
        wndclass.hInstance = hInstance;
        wndclass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
        wndclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
        wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
        wndclass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
        wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName;
        if (!RegisterClass(&wndclass))
        { 
            MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("This program requires Windows NT!"), szAppName, MB_ICONERROR);
        }
        DEVMODEW display_mode;
        if (EnumDisplaySettingsW(NULL, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, &display_mode))
        {
            DWORD window_style = WS_CAPTION | WS_MINIMIZE | WS_SYSMENU | WS_VISIBLE;
            RECT window_rect;
            window_rect.right = display_mode.dmPelsWidth;
            window_rect.bottom = display_mode.dmPelsHeight;
            window_rect.left = window_rect.top = 0;
    
            AdjustWindowRectEx(&window_rect, window_style, FALSE, 0);
            max_right = window_rect.right - window_rect.left;
            max_bottom = window_rect.bottom - window_rect.top;
            HWND window_handle = CreateWindowEx(0, wndclass.lpszClassName,
                TEXT("the hello program"),
                window_style,
                CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                max_right,
                max_bottom,
                NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
                
            ShowWindow(window_handle, iCmdShow);
            UpdateWindow(window_handle);
    
            if (window_handle)
            {
                RECT client_rect;
                GetClientRect(window_handle, &client_rect);
            }
        }
    
        while (GetMessageW(&msg,NULL,0,0))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessageW(&msg);
        }
        return msg.wParam;
    }
    
    LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam)
    {
        HDC hdc;
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        RECT rect;
        switch (message)
        {
        case WM_CREATE:
        case WM_PAINT:
            hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            return 0;
        case WM_GETMINMAXINFO:
            ((MINMAXINFO*)lParam)->ptMaxSize = { max_right,max_bottom };
            ((MINMAXINFO*)lParam)->ptMaxTrackSize = { max_right,max_bottom };
            return 0;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        }
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use function `GetSystemMetrics(...)`.
This function calculate size(resolution) of screen.

For X and Y coordinate, see my example to set variables(use in CreateWindowEx, where set a width and height of window.)Example:

```
int x = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
int y = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
```

Comment: The x and y variable are the CLIENT SIZE that I want, which I already got with EnumDisplaySettings function. CreateWindowExW don't want the client size, it wants the TOTAL window size, including borders and title bar, which I already got too. The problem is that it is not giving me want I ask.

Comment: I've already edited several of your answer and added a reason in the editing comments: please stop adding "please like" in answers. That's asking for upvotes, which you sbouldn't do on Stack Overflow. Some users will downvote your posts for that. I'll edit this one, too, but please don't add it in future posts.